# How can I make this query run faster

Tags: php, mysql

I am running this query on my website in order to find a ToDo list based on specific criteria. But it runs too slow and it is probably possible to write it in another way.

```
SELECT * FROM lesson WHERE 
id IN 
(SELECT `lesson_id` FROM `localization_logging` 
WHERE `language_id` = 2 AND `action_id` = 1) 
AND `id` NOT IN 
(SELECT `lesson_id` FROM `localization_logging` 
WHERE `language_id` = 2 AND `part_id` = 1 AND `action_id` = 6)
```

What the query does is that it looks in the lesson table to find all lesson list names and then checks if a specific task is done. If the task is done in one todo than show it in the next. Action 1 is done but not action 6 in this case.

I hope I'm explaining this good enough. On my local machine the query takes 1.8 seconds, and sometimes I have to print multiple lists next to each others and then it takes 1.8 times the lists which makes the page load super slow.

Comment: first is to see what the database do run : EXPLAIN yourQuery; and post the result then we can see what happend

Answer (score 0):

Something like this for mark id as completed:

```
SELECT l.*, SUM(ll.action_id=6) completed FROM lesson l
INNER JOIN localization_logging ll ON ll.lesson_id = l.id
WHERE ll.language_id = 2 AND 
(
 ll.action_id = 1
  OR 
 ll.action_id = 6 AND ll.part_id == 1
)
GROUP BY l.id
```

And now we can wrap it with:

```
SELECT t.* FROM (...) t WHERE t.completed = 0
```

Comment: Assuming `only_full_group_by` setting allows  the non-standard group by syntax

Answer (score 0):

You'll usually get faster queries filtering rows with `INNER/LEFT JOIN`, but you need to test it.

```
SELECT lesson.* FROM lesson
INNER JOIN localization_logging task1
    ON lesson.id = task1.lesson_id
LEFT JOIN localization_logging task2
    ON lesson.id = task2.lesson_id
    AND task2.language_id = 2
    AND task2.part_id = 1
    AND task2.action_id = 6
WHERE task1.language_id = 2
AND task1.action_id = 1
AND task2.lesson_id IS NULL
```

Second table is joined on multiple conditions, but have to list them within `ON` clause because only results that were in result "force joined" as nulls (left join means left side stays no matter what) are required.

Btw. You'll get multiple rows from `lesson` if `task1` condition is not limiting results to one row - `GROUP BY lesson.id` then.